# g8 ripla/vaadin-scala => scala.MatchError: 0.13.0

Tags: scala, sbt, vaadin7, giter8

I would like to create a scala project with vaadin using giter8 but there's a problem:

```
new-host-3:sms oliviersaint-eve$ g8 ripla/vaadin-scala

Template for Vaadin Scala projects.

package [com.example]: lorry.mars2013
name [Vaadin Scala project]: Test6
classname [VaadinScala]:

Template applied in ./test6

new-host-3:sms oliviersaint-eve$ cd Test6
new-host-3:Test6 oliviersaint-eve$ ls
build.sbt   project     src
new-host-3:Test6 oliviersaint-eve$ sbt
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/oliviersaint-eve/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[error] scala.MatchError: 0.13.0 (of class java.lang.String)
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? q
```

I am using a mac(mac os 10.7.5), with g8 0.5.3, sbt 0.13.0, and java 1.7.0_45.

can you help me?

EDIT: @Jacek:
sbt about =>

```
new-host-3:poubelle oliviersaint-eve$ sbt about
[info] Set current project to poubelle (in build file:/Users/oliviersaint-eve/sms/poubelle/)
[info] This is sbt 0.13.0
[info] The current project is {file:/Users/oliviersaint-eve/sms/poubelle/}poubelle 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.10.2
[info]
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.10.2
```

Files/Directories in "test6":
*build.sbt:

```
name := "Test6"

scalaVersion := "2.9.2"

seq(webSettings: _*)

resolvers += "Vaadin add-ons repository" at "http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons"

// basic dependencies
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"com.vaadin" % "vaadin" % "6.8.2",
"org.vaadin.addons" % "scaladin" % "2.0.0",
"org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "8.0.4.v20111024" % "container"
)
```

directories:
*src/main/scala/lorry/mars2013/VaadinScalaApplication.scala:

```
package lorry.mars2013

import vaadin.scala._

class VaadinScalaApplication extends Application("Test6") {
override val main: ComponentContainer = new VerticalLayout {
    margin = true
    components += Label("This Vaadin app uses Scaladin!")
}
}
```

*src/main/scala/lorry/mars2013/VaadinScalaWidgetset.gwt.xml:

```
<!-- Add widgetset modules from add-ons here. E.g.
<inherits name="org.vaadin.teemu.ratingstars.gwt.RatingStarsWidgetset" />
-->
</module>
```

*src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web/xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="VaadinScala" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>Test6</display-name>
<context-param>
    <description>
    Vaadin production mode</description>
    <param-name>productionMode</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Test6</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.ApplicationServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <description>Vaadin application class to start</description>
        <param-name>application</param-name>
        <param-value>lorry.mars2013.VaadinScalaApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <!--<init-param>
        <description>Application widgetset</description>
            <param-name>widgetset</param-name>
            <param-value>lorry.mars2013.VaadinScalaWidgetset</param-value>
        </init-param>-->
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Test6</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

thanks!
I did not very understood what you mean with text format; do you want me to provide you with links to the files in order to try by yourself(via "pastebin" for example)?

Comment: What's in `.sbt/0.13/plugins` folder? It appears SBT can't load the project. Can you execute `sbt` in any other **empty** directory to cross out issues with the global configuration?

Comment: hello, sbt in an empty directory works without error, the ">" is displayed and sbt waits for a command. In the .sbt/0.13/plugins directory there is : "build.sbt", a directory "project" and a "target".Should I remove all this stuff?(the build.sbt contains a resolver & the declaration of the plugin sbt-idea.)

Comment: What's the result of `sbt about` in an **empty* directory? What are the files in the project created by g8? What's their content? Could you add their content to the question (because of formatting in comment could make it unreadable). Thanks.